# Как сделать так, чтоб блок не мог стать меньше указанной ширины (даже без содержимого)?

Tags: html, css, width

У меня есть блок с текстом. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы несмотря на содержимое этого блока, он в любом случае не мог стать меньше, чем, например 300рх.

Для этого я задаю блоку `min-width: 300px`, но! почему, когда у меня совсем нет текста в этом блоке, все вообще пропадает (несмотря на то, что минимальная ширина этого блока - 300рх). Почему так происходит?

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: yellow;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: `min-width` - это ограничитель, но не задание размера. Добавьте ещё простой `width: 100px;`. И где у Вас `height` ? Скорее всего блок схлопывается по высоте.

Comment: @UModeL ах, да, точно! С `height` все работает как надо

Comment: `inline-block` определяет размер по содержимому, если блок пустой и высоты нет, то видно его не будет

Comment: @Doofy: блок может быть пустым, без указания `height` и всё же может быть видим... например, если у него есть `padding` :)